# Таблица из кнопок не выводится полностью

Tags: javascript, html

```
    function createTable(row,col){
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    document.body.prepend(table);
    for (i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = '<button></button>';
        document.body.prepend(tr);

      for (j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            let td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = '<button></button>';
            document.body.prepend(td);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы таблица полностью заполнялась кнопками?

Comment: Тут лишняя вставка кнопки в строку: tr.innerHTML = '<button></button>';

Comment: Почему вы в `tr` вставляете кнопку? Почему вы `tr` и `td` вставляете в `body`, а не в таблицу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function createTable(row,col){
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    for(i = 0; i < col; i++){
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            table.appendChild(tr);

        for(j = 0; j < row; j++){
            var td = document.createElement('td');
                tr.appendChild(td);
                td.innerHTML = '<button>Ok</button>';
        };
    };
};
createTable(5,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    button {
      background-color: white;
      height: 28px;
      width: 28px;
    }
    
    table {
      border: 20px;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, 
      maximum- 
        scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    const height = prompt('Введите количество строк таблицы');
    const width = prompt('Введите количество столбцов таблицы');

    function tableCreate() {
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      var tbl = document.createElement('table');

      var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
      for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = '<button></button>';


        for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          td.innerHTML = '<button></button>';
          tr.appendChild(td)
        }

        tbdy.appendChild(tr);
      }

      tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
      body.appendChild(tbl)
    }
    tableCreate(height, width);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `tr.innerHTML = '<button></button>';` - вот это зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Иногда бывает легче работать со строкой, чем заморачиваться со вставками)

```js
let mama = document.getElementById('mama');
mama.innerHTML = createTable(5, 5, "<button></button>");

function createTable(cel, row, content = 0){
  let td = multiStr("<td>" + content + "</td>", cel);
  let tr = multiStr("<tr>" +   td    + "</tr>" , row);

  return '<table class="common-table">' + tr + '</table>';
}

function multiStr(str, times = 2){
  return new Array(times).fill(str).join(""); // (*)
}
```

```css
.common-table { border-collapse: collapse; }
.common-table tr:nth-child(2n)   { background-color: #fff1ba; }
.common-table tr:nth-child(2n-1) { background-color: #ffe2aa; }
.common-table td { border: 1px solid #b89868; padding: 5px; }
.common-table button { width: 20px; height: 20px; }
```

```html
<div id="mama"></div>
```

(*) `new Array(times).fill(str).join("");` — «Умножение» строки. Дословный перевод: Создать новый массив. Элементов: `times` штук. На каждой позиции поставить строку `str` и объединить всё в одну строчку, вставив между ними пустую `""`

Comment: А когда у него появится вопрос вида: *Я создаю таблицу с помощью `"<td>" + content + "</td>"`, но у меня в `content` попался **<a** и все сломалось. Что делать?* Вы будете советовать не использовать такой подход?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Уже пусть сам додумается не оставлять **<a>** пустым) Вопрос же конкретно про заполнение одинаковыми кнопками.

Comment: ТС в `tr` вставляет `button`. А вы хотите от него, что бы он задумывался о высоком. Жестоко :-)

Comment: А если в `content` будет хранится то, что пользователь ввел, а не заранее определенная разметка?